# OpenMP and C++: this pointer

Tags: c++, openmp

Is `this` pointer always shared in OpenMP?

Compiler does not complain about following code, despite `default(none)`:

```
#pragma omp parallel for default(none), shared(n)
for ( SInt i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    f( i, this );  // f is some function.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenMP standard defines data-sharing attribute rules for **variables** referenced in your code. Anyhow, according to the C++ standard draft (n3242 9.3.2) `this` is not a variable but a **prvalue expression** (emphasis mine):

> In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, **the keyword this is
>   a prvalue expression** whose value is the address of the object for
>   which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of
>   a class X is X*. If the member function is declared const, the type of
>   this is const X*, if the member function is declared volatile, the
>   type of this is volatile X*, and if the member function is declared
>   const volatile, the type of this is const volatile X*.